# How do I calculate power of this combination?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

How did they come to the expression for total power calculated when both the current source and the voltage source were active?

Comment: The term " a source being inactive" must be agreed to solve this. If we make an assumption that being inactive means for the voltage source to be a short circuit and for the current source to be simply clipped off you will get the shown result by applying superposition. If "being inactive" means something else the things would be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current and voltage are linear, but power is quadratic. So you can't apply superposition on power directly. But you can find either voltage or current using superposition and then work power:

Let \$V_1\$ be the voltage across \$R\$ when current source is open.
Let \$V_2\$ be the voltage across \$R\$ when voltage source is shorted.
Then by superposition, overall voltage across \$R\$ will be \$V_{tot} = V_1+V_2\$.

\$P_1 = V_1^2/R \Rightarrow V_1 =\sqrt{P_1 R} \$

\$P_2 = V_2^2/R \Rightarrow V_2 =\sqrt{P_2 R} \$

\$P_{tot} = V_{tot}^2/R=(V_1+V_2)^2/R = \dfrac{(\sqrt{P_1R}+\sqrt{P_2R})^2}{R}=(\sqrt{P_1}+\sqrt{P_2})^2\$